# Associate post with custom post type

Tags: wordpress

I've registered a new type in my custom theme like so (inside function.php):

```
    register_post_type( 'programmering',
    array(
        'labels' => array(
            'name' => __( 'Programmering' ),
            'singular_name' => __( 'Programmering' )
        ),
    'public' => true,
    'has_archive' => true,
    )
);}
```

And the new post type is present when I var_dump get_post_types() but I don't know how to associate a post with that type? When I create a new post it's post type is still "post".